# Error in seq_len 2 arguments passed to 'seq_len' which requires 1 using foreach package in R?

Tags: r, loops, foreach, parallel-processing, doparallel

I am trying to run a for loop in R using parallel processing. I want to do a grid search on my ranger model to test different combinations in the model to see where I can best tune the model. In order for me to test different tuning methods I need to run a loop on the data here is the code:

```
# Creating simulations    -------------------------------------------------
hyper_grid <- expand.grid(
  num.trees = c(300),
  quant = c(0.94,0.95),
  mtry = c(5,4),
  nodSize = c(50,40),
  num_weeks_train = c(6,5),
  rmse = NA
);
```

**For loop**

```
foreach (j = seq_len(nrow(hyper_grid), .packages ='magrittr' )) %dopar% {
  print(j)
  # j = 1
  fit = BVR_model_sim(
    num_weeks_train = hyper_grid$num_weeks_train[j],
    data = df_base,
    quntile = hyper_grid$quant[j],
    start_week = 202001,
    end_week = 202016,
    ntrees = hyper_grid$num.trees[j],
    randMtry = hyper_grid$mtry[j],
    nodSize = hyper_grid$nodSize[j]
  )
  
  # hyper_grid$rmse[j] <- fit$prediction_error
  
  sim_result <- rbind(sim_result, cbind(hyper_grid[j, ], as.data.frame(fit$output)))
  
  print(sim_result)
};
```

**Error**

```
Error in seq_len(nrow(hyper_grid), .packages = "magrittr") : 
  2 arguments passed to 'seq_len' which requires 1
```

**My Non-Parallelized-loop that runs perfect fine but slow looks as such**

```
for (j in seq_len(nrow(hyper_grid)))  {
  print(j)
  # j = 1
  fit = BVR_model_sim(
    num_weeks_train = hyper_grid$num_weeks_train[j],
    data = df_base,
    quntile = hyper_grid$quant[j],
    start_week = 202001,
    end_week = 202016,
    ntrees = hyper_grid$num.trees[j],
    randMtry = hyper_grid$mtry[j],
    nodSize = hyper_grid$nodSize[j]
  )
  
  # hyper_grid$rmse[j] <- fit$prediction_error
  
  sim_result <- rbind(sim_result, cbind(hyper_grid[j, ], as.data.frame(fit$output)))
  
  print(sim_result)
};
```

Comment: Close a second parenthesis after `nrow` and remove the second close parenthesis at the end of that code line. This seems to be a simple typo, a reason to vote to close. Is it?

Comment: im not quite following, could you post the code changes?

Comment: `foreach (j = seq_len(nrow(hyper_grid)), .packages ='magrittr') %dopar% {`